# Like ASCII, how characters are assigned binary values in UNICODE?

Tags: unicode, ascii, bit, representation

ASCII uses a 8 bit system. Each character is assigned a unique ASCII value. But UNICODE uses 32 or 64 bit representation. So how the characters are assigned values there? Does C/C++ use UNICODE?

Comment: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/unicode.html

Comment: http://kunststube.net/encoding

Comment: This is off-topic (not about programming, except the last question, to which the correct answer is “maybe”), too broad, and based on wrong assumptions (ASCII is a 7-bit system, and Unicode as such does not assign binary values, it assigns code numbers), and the Unicode transfer encodings use 8, 16, or 32 bits per character (never 64).

Comment: Unicode does not use 32, 64 or other number of bits. Read this: http://utf8everywhere.org.

Answer (score 0):

From [this](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2003/cmsc311/Notes/Data/ascii.html)

> To convert ASCII to Unicode, take all one byte ASCII codes, and zero-extend them to 16 bits. That should be the Unicode version of the ASCII characters.

Unicode in c/c++ look into [this](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/unicode.html)

Answer (score 0):

Unicode first and foremost defines characters by a code point. This is simply a giant table which specifies that the letter "A" (LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A) has the code point U+0041, "ท" (THAI CHARACTER THO THAHAN) has the code point U+0E17 and so on and so forth.

There are then several Unicode *encodings* which encode these code points into physical bits. UCS-2 was an early encoding which is now superseded by UTF-16. UTF-32 exists as well, but UTF-8 has become the de facto standard Unicode encodings. Each encoding works differently and has different pros and cons, read their specification in detail if you are interested. The most obvious difference is that UTF-8 uses *a minimum* of 8 bits per character, UTF-16 *a minimum* of 16 bits and UTF-32 32 bits.